# Unpickle class instances by interating over a list

Tags: python, class, filenames, pickle

I am trying to unpickle various class instances which are saved in separate .pkl files by iterating over a list containing all the class instances (each class instance appends itself to the appropriate list when instantiated).

This **works**:

```
# LOAD IN INGREDIENT INSTANCES
for each in il:
    with open('Ingredients/{}.pkl'.format(each), 'rb') as f:
        globals()[each] = pickle.load(f)
```

For example, one ingredient is `Aubergine`:

```
print(Aubergine)
```

output:

```
Name:         Aubergine 
Price:        £1.00 
Portion Size: 1
```

However, this **doesn't work**:

```
# LOAD IN RECIPE INSTANCES
for each in rl:
    with open('Recipes/{}.pkl'.format(each.name), 'rb') as f:
        globals()[each] = pickle.load(f)
```

I can only assume that the issue stems from `each.name` being used for the file names of the recipes, whereas `each` is used for the ingredient file names. This is intentional, however, as the `name` attribute of the recipes is formatted for the end-user (i.e. contains white space etc.) I think this may be the issue, but I am not sure.

Both the ingredient and recipe classes use:

```
def __repr__(self):
    return self.name
```

For example:

I have a recipe class instance `SausageAubergineRagu`, for which `self.name` is `'Sausage & Aubergine Ragu'`, and this is inside the list `rl`. I have tried testing this individually:

input:

```
rl
```

output:

```
[Sausage & Aubergine Ragu]
```

So I believe that this code:

```
# LOAD IN RECIPE INSTANCES
for each in rl:
    with open('Recipes/{}.pkl'.format(each.name), 'rb') as f:
        globals()[each] = pickle.load(f)
```

...should result in this:

```
with open('Recipes/Sausage & Aubergine Ragu.pkl', 'rb') as f:
    globals()[SausageAubergineRagu] = pickle.load(f)
```

But attempting to access the recipe class instances results in a NameError.

**One final note** - please **don't** ask why I am doing things this way. Instead help me to address and solve the problem, so I can make it work, and understand what is going on. Appreciated :)

Comment: Why is the question being down-voted?

Answer (score 0):

The `NameError` you are getting is Python telling you that you are trying to use a variable that hasn't been defined yet.

You aren't defining `SausageAubergineRagu` before you use it in this line:

```
globals()[SausageAubergineRagu] = pickle.load(f)
```

In your first example, you are adding keys and values to `globals`.  You are using instances of recipes (`each`) as keys, and the pickled data as values.

In your second example, you are attempting to do the same thing, but instead of using instances of recipes (`each`) as keys, you are using `SausageAubergineRagu`, which is undefined.

How is Python supposed to know what `SausageAubergineRagu` is?  If you want that line to work, you will need to define it first, or use something that is already defined, like `each`, which is what you do in your other snippet.

Honestly, using instances of custom classes as keys in `globals` seems bizarre to me anyway (usually people use strings), but since you apparently want to make it work, the answer is simple:

Define `SausageAubergineRagu` before attempting to use it as a key in a dictionary.

Comment: I am trying to define it. That is the whole point. It works with the ingredient class but not with the recipe class. In my question I have demonstrated an instance of the ingredient class instance `Aubergine` having been successfully unpickled.

Comment: Okay so this explains the name error where I have tried to write in the code, but when it is still using `each` it still doesn't work. If I run the code and call the class is says it is not defined. Any ideas?

Comment: Probably because you are using instances of your recipe as keys in `globals`.  Try using `globals()[each.name] = pickle.load(f)` instead.  Using a string as the key makes much more sense anyway.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean? This is how I think it is, please correct me if I have it wrong.

`each` is used because each in the list is the actual instance of the class; I'm simply unpickling it from a previous session.

Also in the case of the example I've used, `each` would be the class instance SausageAubergineRagu, whereas `each.name` would be the string "Sausage & Aubergine Ragu", so I wouldn't be able to call attributes on it because as it would be a string.

Comment: @JakeStokes Why do you want to use the instance of the class itself as the key?  Do you understand how `globals()` works?  Why not use the string `"SausageAubergineRagu"` as the key, then you can use it in your namespace like any other variable.